# Apply POS tag to nested list

Tags: python, for-loop, nlp, pos-tagger

I'm trying to go through multiple sentences in a text. Each sentence is stored in nested list structure (i.e. a list of each sentence in the form of a list). I then want to apply POS tag to each 'token' in the sentence and store in another nested list structure. Ultimately this is so that I can add this to a dataframe and export to excel in 1 column (where each row is a sentence).

The trouble I'm having is the POS tag list only seems to capture the last sentence in the text. Here is part of the code.

```
for sentences in doc1.sents: #iterates over sentences in doc
     for match_id, start, end in phrase_matcher(nlp(sentences.text)):  
          if nlp.vocab.strings[match_id] in ["key"]: 
          found_sentences = sentences.text
          duplicate_sentence_list.append(found_sentences)                        
      all_separated_words_list.append(text_preprocessing(found_sentences))
          tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
          tags = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)
          pos_list.append(tags)
```

When I try adding the POS tag to a for loop like below:

```
for sentences in doc1.sents: #iterates over sentences in doc
     for match_id, start, end in phrase_matcher(nlp(sentences.text)):  
          if nlp.vocab.strings[match_id] in ["key"]: 
          found_sentences = sentences.text
          duplicate_sentence_list.append(found_sentences)                        
          all_separated_words_list.append(text_preprocessing(found_sentences))
          for i in found_sentences:
              pos_list.append(nltk.pos_tag(i))
```

i get this error:

TypeError: tokens: expected a list of strings, got a string

When i change the for loop to use the nested list (all_separated_words_list) I get this error:

> ### `Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor
>
> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
> /var/folders/6g/n1v5s0vj77xc2htytg4spx_r0000gn/T/ipykernel_17689/361983526.py in 
> 14                         all_separated_words_list.append(text_preprocessing(found_sentences))
> 15                         for i in found_sentences:
> 16                             pos_list.append(nltk.pos_tag(all_separated_words_list))
> 17                         #     tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(i)
> 18                         #     tags = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)
>
> ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nltk/tag/**init**.py in pos_tag(tokens, tagset, lang)
> 164     """
> 165     tagger = _get_tagger(lang)
> 166     return _pos_tag(tokens, tagset, tagger, lang)
> 167
> 168
>
> ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nltk/tag/**init**.py in _pos_tag(tokens, tagset, tagger, lang)
> 121
> 122     else:
> 123         tagged_tokens = tagger.tag(tokens)
> 124         if tagset:  # Maps to the specified tagset.
> 125             if lang == "eng":
>
> ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nltk/tag/perceptron.py in tag(self, tokens, return_conf, use_tagdict)
> 178         output = []
> ...
> 277         if word.isdigit() and len(word) == 4:
> 278             return "!YEAR"
> 279         if word and word[0].isdigit():
>
> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'isdigit'`

So I'm not too sure how to proceed. Would appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, it's telling you that it expected a string, but instead it got a list.

```python
for i in found_sentences:
    pos_list.append(nltk.pos_tag(i))
```

I suspect what's happening is that at this point you think you're giving it a single sentence, and then trying to iterate over the words in it, but `found_sentences` is actually list of sentences. So when it iterates over them it's finding a list (the tokenized sentence) instead of a string (the individual word).

Go back over your code again, looking at the output of each line and you'll be able to see where it is going wrong.